# Symfony 4 Composer scripts

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I've just installed Symfony 4 project and found this section in `composer.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
...
```

I've found that section `auto-scripts` is handled somehow differently by the Composer: key is a command to `bin/console` and value is a command "type" (In this case it's Symfony's). As it is not documented on Composer website, I assume it's not legal definition, but it works, and my question is how the Composer knows how to execute such commands? How Composer knows what is `symfony-cmd`?

Comment: It is part of the Symfony Flex composer plugin so it is legal.  I have never tracked down exactly where it is defined but probably somewhere in [here](https://github.com/symfony/flex).  It is the same code that lets you do thing like "composer require server" and other magic.

Answer (score 11):

It's as [Cerad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1146363/cerad) says. `auto-script` is parsed by Symfony/Flex and the "right side" of a command:executable pair is processed by [this switch-case](https://github.com/symfony/flex/blob/3e8d6c423092ca89dd8fb998ddb9d7a91139e52f/src/ScriptExecutor.php#L80).

```
switch ($type) {
    case 'symfony-cmd':
        return $this->expandSymfonyCmd($cmd);
    case 'php-script':
        return $this->expandPhpScript($cmd);
    case 'script':
        return $cmd;
```

Therefore Composer documentation can not say a word about that as it is Symfony-specific.

Personally don't like the mixing of standard Composer sections with custom ones on the composer.json root level. It simply confuses me and draws me into silent Composer documentation.
Also the naming itself, `auto-script`, should be better. Something less magic and more self-explanatory, like `flex-script`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it uses `extra` configuration located in `composer.json`

```
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",

    ...
},
```

Few days ago when I was migrating an application from 2.8 to 3.4, I had some trouble with these definitions.

I also had to clear composer's cache.

Comment: Good guess but nope.