# Is it possible to integrate custom Symfony Console commands into a composer package's scripts?

Tags: php, composer-php

I know it's possible to include simple CLI scripts into Composer's `scripts`/`scripts-descriptions` list.
It's also possible to point static methods or functions to be executed as Composer scripts.

I know, under the hood, it uses the Symfony Console library.

Thus, is there any chance it's possible to include custom Symfony Console scripts into the main list of scripts a project uses, besides writing WET code and repeating all scripts and descriptions into `composer.json`?

> Note: this is not a Symfony question, it's a Composer question - which indeed uses Symfony Console, but it's not related to the framework as a whole. It's custom `Command` subclasses which I want to add to `composer.json` without repetitive descriptions and commands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony 4 Composer scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702990/symfony-4-composer-scripts)

Comment: Nice try! But not really. That seems to be Symfony-specific, I'm looking for a pure solution, based only in Composer (and it's usage of Symfony Console, but not through the Symfony framework as a whole).

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Which kind of scripts do you refer to then?

Comment: I wrote a couple of scripts with Symfony Console. Then, I want to see them mixed with  what `composer list` shows and runs, just like scripts defined under the `scripts` key in `composer.json`. Thus... Symfony Console commands integrated into composer package scripts. First I mentioned the composer scripts, then usage of Symfony Console. I thought the association was clear enough.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't use the comment section for that

Comment: Maybe https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md#command-provider could help?

Comment: But... I've already edited mentioning it's not about the Symfony framework. I'll add a mention to the library, just in case. I guess it's enough, then?

Comment: Hmmm I guess that sort of helps, but it's still quite an overshoot on what I was expecting - having to create another package just to handle scripts from a project is way too much for this kind of thing. I guess you could make it an answer, so it's at least worth the votes? haha